# Jinja IF statement doesn't work with script html tags

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have two lines of code in my Flask application's `<head>` section that I would like to hide from some users. I am using an if statement to achieve it, but it seems not working. The syntax seems proper for me, the page loads without any errors. I tried to put the two script sources into different if statements and checked several times if the `links` variable has a wrong value, but none of them is the reason.

So I am assuming something that `<script>` elements placed inside Jinja if statements has some restrictions or if statements won't work outside the `<body>`. (The `{{links}}` variable inside the `<body>` writes out the `'display'` value). How can it be done, or is it not possible outside the `<body>`?

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
    
    <title>{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}</title>

        {% if links == 'display' %}

        {% block firebase1 %}<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-app.js"></script>{% endblock %}
        {% block firebase2 %}<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>{% endblock %}

        {% endif %}

{% block content %}
```

{% block content %}

```
> #from my layout.html
> 
> <!doctype html> <html lang="en">
>     <head>
>         <meta charset="utf-8">
>         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
>         <link href="/static/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
>         <title>{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}</title>
>         {% block firebase1 %}{% endblock %}
>         {% block firebase2 %}{% endblock %}
>     </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your blocks in your main template references any block names in the parent (layout.html). There is nowhere to insert the content from your lower template.

If you have the following in `layout.html`:

```
<!doctype html> <html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% block firebase %}{% endblock %}
```

You can then use a conditional to decide which content to place into the block in your actual template:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block firebase %}
  {% if links == 'display' %}
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: My bad. I copied a wrong code there from a previous try. The actual code is like what you posted but unfortunately still wrong. I already tried to put that snippet into a different file and include it, without any success.

Comment: In that case, please update your question with actually correct content and your call to render the template, so that the problem can be reproduced. If your question doesn't contain code that actually represents the problem, no-one can help you